# Issues using Chrome-Pdf recipie on IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, jsreport

I am using the jsreport nuget packages in an asp.net core application. I am able to generate my pdf reports on my local machine however I run into an issue when I try to generate reports with the asp.net core application running in IIS. Whenever I attempt to run a report, it ultimately times out and gives me the following error:

```
Error rendering report: instance has been daemonized and initialized successfully (pid: 2480)A critical error occurred while trying to execute the render command: Timeout Error: pdf generation not completed after 40000ms
```

Some information about my setup:

- The app is being hosed in IIS on a Server2008R2 machine
- The IIS app is running under the Network Authority user.
- I have given the application pool full permissions on the jsreport
  folder deployed with the ASP.Net Core application.
- I have give the application pool full permissions on the jsreport
  folder in C:\Windows\Temp

Here is what I have been able to verify so far:

- I can navigate to the jsreport folder in the deployed asp.net core
  application, run `jsreport start` from the command line and enter
  jsreport studio. From there I can run my reports with sample data
  sizes comparable to what I would expect at runtime, and they export
  to PDF just fine.
- I can successfully make a request to the IIS hosted asp.net core application to render a plain HTML report.
- The reports run just fine when being hosted on my local machine, outside of IIS.

It seems like there is some kind of issue with IIS accessing Chrome and doing the pdf conversion. Are there any additional steps I need to take to get chrome-pdf conversion working when hosting with IIS?